# How To Change Apple ID associated with Apple TV?

Tags: apple-id, appletv, settings

I'd like to change the Apple ID that is associated with my Apple TV HD.  It appears that this can't be changed in the UI.  Do I need to do a factory reset?

Comment: https://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/09/04/apple-tv-delete-apple-id-email/ - didn't this help ?

Comment: What version of the ATV?

Answer (score 1):

You shoul find it in Settings > Users and Accounts > then click on the iCloud bar where's written the email of the currently active Apple ID and then you have the option to sign out. Then Sign back in with the account you prefer.